# How to define unrecognized rules in Ocamlyacc

Tags: ocaml, yacc, lex, ocamllex, ocamlyacc

I'm working on company projet, where i have to create a compilator for a  language using Ocamlyacc and Ocamllex. I want to know if is it possible to define a rule in my Ocamlyacc Parser that can tell me that no rules of my grammar matching the syntax of an input.

I have to insist that i'am a beginner in Ocamllex/Ocamlyacc

Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no rule in your grammar matches the input, then `Parsing.Parse_error` exception is raised. Usually, this is what you want.

There is also a special token called `error` that allows you to resynchronize your parser state. You can use it in your rules, as it was a real token produced by a lexer, cf., `eof` token.

Also, I would suggest to use `menhir` instead of more venerable `ocamlyacc`. It is easier to use and debug, and it also comes with a good library of predefined grammars.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what i needed !

Answer (score 1):

When you write a compiler for a language, the first step is to run your lexer and to check if your program is good from a lexical point of view.

See the below example :

```
{
  open Parser        (* The type token is defined in parser.mli *)
  exception Eof
}
  rule token = parse
            [' ' '\t']     { token lexbuf }     (* skip blanks *)
          | ['\n' ]        { EOL }
          | ['0'-'9']+ as lxm { INT(int_of_string lxm) }
          | '+'            { PLUS }
          | '-'            { MINUS }
          | '*'            { TIMES }
          | '/'            { DIV }
          | '('            { LPAREN }
          | ')'            { RPAREN }
          | eof            { raise Eof }
```

It's a lexer to recognize some arithmetic expressions.

If your lexer accepts the input then you give the sequence of lexemes to the parser which try to find if a AST can be build with the specified grammar. See :

```
%token <int> INT
        %token PLUS MINUS TIMES DIV
        %token LPAREN RPAREN
        %token EOL
        %left PLUS MINUS        /* lowest precedence */
        %left TIMES DIV         /* medium precedence */
        %nonassoc UMINUS        /* highest precedence */
        %start main             /* the entry point */
        %type <int> main
        %%
        main:
            expr EOL                { $1 }
        ;
        expr:
            INT                     { $1 }
          | LPAREN expr RPAREN      { $2 }
          | expr PLUS expr          { $1 + $3 }
          | expr MINUS expr         { $1 - $3 }
          | expr TIMES expr         { $1 * $3 }
          | expr DIV expr           { $1 / $3 }
          | MINUS expr %prec UMINUS { - $2 }
        ;
```

This is a little program to parse arithmetic expression. A program can be rejected at this step because there is no rule of the grammar to apply in order to have an AST at the end. **There is no way to define unrecognized rules but you need to write a grammar which define how a program can be accepted or rejected.**

```
let _ =
  try
    let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel stdin in
    while true do
      let result = Parser.main Lexer.token lexbuf in
      print_int result; print_newline(); flush stdout
    done
  with Lexer.Eof ->
    exit 0
```

If your compile the lexer, the parser and the last program, you have :

1. `1 + 2` is accepted because there is no error lexical errors and an AST can be build corresponding to this expression.
2. `1 ++ 2` is rejected : no lexical errors but there is no rule to build a such AST.

You can found more documentation here  : http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual026.html